# RabbitMQ: How to create listener on "subscription added"

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I'm using https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop to get all subscriptions by exchangeName. This works for me but I have to ask rabbitmq about subscriptions every time when I need to iterate over them in case any new subscription has been added.
Is there any way to add listener in my application to know if any subscription added?

Or maybe RabbitMQ provides any other tool for adding such listeners?

Comment: I haven't found such api so I decide to share this information through hazelcast - put info about new subscription into hazelcast map and add listener on changes in hazelcast map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hop` is based on management HTTP API.

You can't add a listener on it.

The management UI executes the `HTTP API` each `X seconds` to get the information about subscriptions/queues/exchanges etc.

Comment: Does rabbitmq provide any other tool to add such listeners?